# If User Input is equal to any value of an array

Tags: c#

I have an array of arrays, called **numberSets.**

numberSets has 4 arrays called numberSet1, numberSet2, numberSet3 and numberSet4.

- numberSet1 has 6 values: 0, 5, 25, 50, 100, 250.
- numberSet2 has 6 values: 0, 5, 30, 50, 100, 300.
- numberSet3 has 6 values: 0, 5, 15, 30, 45, 60.
- and numberSet4 has 6 values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 15.

Now I have a For Loop that prompts the user to enter in 4 values at separate times. The first input value must be equal to one number from numberSet1, the second input value must be equal to one number from numberSet2 and so on.

What my problem is trying to write the IF statement. e.g:

```
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (input == numberSets .... ) {
       data[i] = input; //The data variable has 4 arrays too, for the 4 user inputs.
       Console.Write("Wowa wee wah, Great success!");
}
else {
       Conosle.Write("Sorry you must enter the correct values");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```cs
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (numberSets[i].Contains(input))
    {
        // SUCCESS
    }
}
```